# ORACLE Database First EF4 to EF5 in VS2K12: error 0040: The Type XXX is not qualified with a namespace or alias

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, edmx, devart, ef-database-first

I have a `VS2K12` solution with an ORACLE Database-First `.edmx file` connected using `dotConnect` `7.2.96.0`. I have some `uTests` that run against the DB like a charm.

If I change the version of `Entity Framework` (from version 4 to 5) and updating the Project to `Framework 4.5`, the solution compiles but the `uTests` fails with the following errors whenever they try to get the context of the DB:

```
`System.Data.MetadataException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232007
  Message=Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 

AlertingData.ssdl(54,6) : error 0040: The Type NVARCHAR2 is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.

AlertingData.ssdl(57,6) : error 0040: The Type TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.
```

Several of them. Any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set "ColumnTypeCasingConventionCompatibility = false" before the first usage of the context (e.g.: in a static constructor of a partial class) or in *.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.Configuration.OracleEntityProviderConfigurationSection,
      Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=7.2.96.0, Culture=neutral,
      PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
  </configSections>
  <Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity xmlns="http://devart.com/schemas/Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity/1.0">
    <CodeFirstOptions ColumnTypeCasingConventionCompatibility="false"/>
  </Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity>
</configuration>
```

For more information, refer to http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?CodeFirstOptions.html.

Comment: It works, thank you very much, I did not use it before because Naming confusion "CodeFirstOptions" seemed to me only applying if it was CodeFirst Database, that was not my case (DataBase First).